# Проблема со слайдером Slick - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить мою проблему. Я использую в своем проекте слайдер `slick`. Я инициализировал его в футере сайте:

```
function createSlick() {
    $('.gallery').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    createSlick();
});
```

Проблема в том, что на одной странице слайдер работает отлично, но на другой странице его вызов уже не работает. Погуглил и узнал, что вызываю его дважды, что и приводит к такой ошибке. Но мне все равно нужно его запустить на других страницах. Что я могу предпринять для этого ?

Comment: убедитесь, что на второй странице у вас точно присутствует блок с классом `.gallery`

Comment: @teran, Я в этом уверен абсолютно. Такой блок с таким классом на второй странице есть.

Comment: это единственное место на странице, где вызывается метод `.slick()` ?

Comment: @teran, да, я вызываю .slick() только в футере сайта.

Comment: а версия jquery какая? хотя если на одной странице работает, а на другой нет. то jquery тут не при делах должен быть

Comment: @teran, v1.11.1

Comment: попробуйте поменять на какую нить 2.2.1 (ну или что нибудь стабильное из второго) и проверить как будет. вообще написано что требует версию 1.7+, хотя на странице слика и подключен 1.11 и мигрейт до 1.2

Comment: @teran, поменял - не помогло. дело видимо не в jq. буду копать дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная логика решит проблему повторной инициализации слайдера

```
$(".slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick()
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решил вместо slick заюзать owl carousel 2. Owl carosel ошибок в консоль не выдал, на всех остальных страницах заработал без проблем.
Почему Slick так себя ведет - пока не выяснил...

Comment: А еще лучше - Swiper Slider, как по мне, лучший слайдер для любого контента ;)